# UserInfo of UILocalNotification always nil

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, swift3

I am creating simple `UILocalNotification`, without scheduling, just from background with the following code:

```
let n = UILocalNotification()
n.alertBody = "\(nam) \(wat)"
n.userInfo = ["id": id, "t":type.rawValue]
n.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
n.category = "call_chat"
app.scheduleLocalNotification(n)
```

I am printing `userInfo` inside

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification)`

Until here everything is fine. But I need to dismiss some of notifications with the same id later on and create new ones. When I am trying to get them with `UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications` all of them has `userInfo==nil` in iOS9 and `userInfo==["":""]` in iOS10 beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally I find out, that scheduledLocalNotifications doesn't contain notifications, that already shown. The only way is to store them in array, or use `NSKeyArchiver` like said [here](https://developer.sinnerschrader-mobile.com/ios-how-to-remove-a-notification-programmatically-from-ios-notification-center/582/).